# How do I tell Babel not to care about what it doesn't understand?

Tags: babeljs

I have a piece of Javascript code with the decorator and `import` syntax used. I told Babel to transform it per `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` and it complains to me of not giving it the `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators` work, when I don't want to transpile anything but “`import`.”

```
{ SyntaxError: ……\code.mjs: Support for the experimental syntax 'decorators-legacy' isn't currently enabled (9:2):

……

  pos: 184,
  loc: Position { line: 9, column: 1 },
  missingPlugin: [ 'decorators-legacy', 'decorators' ],
  code: 'BABEL_PARSE_ERROR' }
```

---

How do I properly tell

> “Just do your `@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs` job that I gave you and do not ever give a dang about decorator thingies.”

to Babel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of Babel's experimental syntax transformations come in pairs, one of which enables only parsing, and one of which enables parsing and transformation:

- `@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators`
- `@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators`

Since you don't want to transform, you'd want to use `@babel/plugin-syntax-decorators`.